# Upload from camera intent

Tags: android, imageview, android-camera

Currenty working on small app to teach my-self. I need to capture image, show it at imageview and uploadt it. I have managed to create that intent and show image on imageview but currently can't upload it and can't figure it out how? Also have button that uploads image from gallery. Should I use Asynctask? I am lost

Camera intent:

```
mCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA_CAPTURE);
        }
    });
```

Image upload:

```
private void UploadImage (){

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, UploadUrl,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String Response = jsonObject.getString("response");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,Response,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mImageView.setImageResource(0);
                        mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mEditText.setText("");
                        mEditText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    })


    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("name1",mEditText.getText().toString().trim());
            params.put("name2", staticSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim());
            params.put("image",ImageToString(bitmap));

            return params;
        }
    };
```

Image to string

```
    private String ImageToString(Bitmap bitmap){

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte [] imgBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

    return Base64.encodeToString(imgBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should upload byte array of your image below is the code to convert bitmap to byte array.

```
Bitmap bmp = intent.getExtras().get("data"); // your image bitmap
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();  send this b
bmp.recycle(); // recycle your bitmap
```

Comment: You have to upload the image in multipart entity

Comment: have a look  at link https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-upload-image-to-server/

Comment: Just wondering do I have to make that url in database? Didn't see that I was important and thank you for your help I will try it as soon as possible

Comment: That link wasn't really useful